# Showing that $O(o(f))=o(O(f))=o(g)$ if $f=O(g)$

Tags: asymptotics

In *Asymptotic Analysis* by J.D.Murray on page 10 the following question is posed. If $f=O(g)$ show that:
$$O(o(f))=o(O(f))=o(g)$$
I am really confused by what this actually means. How can you have $O(o(f))$? Surely $O$ has to act on a function and $o(f)$ is not a function - rather a statement about the function it equals. Please can someone explain.

Comment: Well, assume that $u\in o(f)$ and $v\in O(f)$. The first equality means $O(u)=o(v)$.

Comment: @Jack By $u\in o(f)$ do you mean a function $u$ such that $u=o(f)$? if not what do you mean - I have never seen $o(f)$ and $O(f)$ treated as sets before.

Comment: $o(f)$ and $O(f)$ are sets of functions with a certain growth condition depending of $f$… so the notation "$u = o(f)$" is kind of confusing… and it seems it confused you. How did you define $o(f)$ and $O(f)$ if not as sets?

Comment: @Gono I must admit I am new to this subject. The only way I have seen them defined is by the definitions given here  http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf.

Comment: @Gono what does $u=o(f)$ mean then in the context of sets?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation

Comment: Both notations mean the same… so if you write $u\in o(f)$ or $u = o(f)$ in both cases it holds $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{u(x)}{f(x)} = 0$$. But I find the $=$-notation confusing because consider that with $u = o(f)$ also $2u = o(f)$  so you could naivly conclude $u = o(f) = 2u$ hence $u = 2u$ what's wrong… that's why the set notation should prefered especially if you are new to that topic…

Comment: @Gono Thanks, I understand the set properties of it now. I am still confused of what $O(O(f))=o(g)$ means. Does it mean the sets are equal (i.e. contain the same elements)? I ask since the next question asks to prove $O(f)O(g)=O(fg)$ but I have read the relation is acutally $O(f)O(g)\subseteq O(fg)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated ([Basin & Rusinowitch, 2004](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C0YBCAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)) in the context of O-notation the equals sign, $=$, means subset or equals, $\subseteq$. We then have to prove:
$$O(o(f)) \subseteq o(O(f))\subseteq o(g)$$

## Showing that $O(o(f))\subseteq o(O(f))$

To show this first statement we do as Jack's advice in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371310/showing-that-oof-oof#comment4887130_2371310) above. We let $u\in O(o(f))$ which means that:
$$ \newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|} \newcommand{\braoket}[3]{\left<#1\right|#2\left|#3\right>} |u| \le k|v| \text{ where } \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \l \f{v}{f}\r =0$$
But:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \l \f{v}{f}\r =0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \l \f{kv}{kf}\r =0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \l \f{u}{kf}\r =0$$
Since $kf \in O(f)$ we have that $u\in o(kf)\in o(O(f))$. Hence every element $u\in O(o(f))$ is also in $o(O(f))$ meaning that $O(o(f))=o(O(f))$ i.e.  $O(o(f))\subseteq o(O(f))$ .

## Showing that $o(O(f))\subseteq o(g)$

Let $u \in o(O(f))$ then:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\l \f{u}{v}\r=0 \text{ where } |v|\le k|f|$$
but since $f\in O(g)$ we have that $|v| \le k_2 |g|$. This implies that:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\l \f{u}{k_2 g}\r=0$$
$$\Rightarrow  \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\l \f{u}{ g}\r=0$$
Hence every $u\in o(O(f))$ is also in $o(g)$ meaning that $o(O(f))=o(g)$ i.e. $o(O(f))\subseteq o(g)$.

Comment: Translating the property $u(x)=o(v(x))$, say when $x\to0$, as $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}=0$$ is problematic since it excludes cases such as $$u(x)=x\sin(1/x)\qquad v(x)=\sin(1/x)$$ for every $x\ne0$.  The correct definition of $u(x)=o(v(x))$ when $x\to0$ is that there exists some function $w$ such that $u(x)=v(x)w(x)$ in a neighborhood of $0$ and $$\lim_{x\to0}w(x)=0$$

Comment: @Did, hmm I like this other definition - but I have never seen it before. Do you by any chance know of any sources that mentions it and where I can read up more?

Comment: @Did: Why it exclude the case you mentioned ?  $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\sin(1/x)}{\sin(1/x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}x=0.$$

Comment: @Surb Because $v(x)=0$ for infinitely many $x$ close to $0$.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification The need to assume the function $v$ is not zero in a neighborhood of the limit point, if one insists on using the ratio definition, is already apparent on [the corresponding WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

Comment: ...One may also note the careful formulation [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/big-o-notation/#landau-notations), clearly tailored to avoid ratios.